# No visible @interface for 'LocationPlugin' declares the selector 'presentViewController:animated:completion:'

Tags: flutter, xcode14, flutter-ios-build

UIAlertController *alert = [[UIAlertController alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location is Disabled"
message:@"To use location, go to your Settings App > Privacy > Location Services."
delegate: self
cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
is causing the error when I am building my Flutter app in Xcode

No visible @interface for 'LocationPlugin' declares the selector 'presentViewController:animated:completion:'

I tried changing the code according to the majority of developers' suggestions. still is causing the issue.

Comment: Your code is badly formatted and not understandable. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask